# Find feature of dataframe high gives smallest error, if we train model with one feature

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have a two dataframes with same lenbgths: Y and X. X has 4 features X1, X2, X3, X4. I want to predict Y using linear regression:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, Y)
Ypred = model.predict(X) # use trained regression model to predict
r = Y-Ypred # compute prediction error (residual)
e = abs(r).mean()
```

Now, i want to train model with one column of X dataframe and then find feature which gives lowest e (error). How could i do that? The idea is using greedy algorithm, but how to do it in python?

Answer (score 0):

You can take your approach and apply a `for` loop to it:

```py
def find_best_feature(X, Y):
    y_preds = []
    for i in range(len(x.columns)):
        model.fit(X.iloc[:,i], Y)
        r = Y - model.predict(X.iloc[:,i], Y)
        y_preds.append((abs(r).mean(), i))
    return np.array(y_preds).min()


find_best_feature(X, Y)
```

This is my implementation. There are other sites and posts on SO regarding greedy algorithms like [this one](https://gist.github.com/gcallah/bb22ea72d8b15fa965d2f50e6798ae50)